# What will be the output of the given code below?

Tags: c, pointers, output, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a =0, b=1, c=2;

    *( ( a+1==1) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
    printf("%d, %d, %d \n", a , b, c );

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain me the solution and output?

Comment: Why don't you compile and run it yourself?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Running it yourself answers the title (but only if one assumes the output in every C implementation will be the same as in the tested C implementation) but not the question asked at the end of the post. Comments like that are unhelpful.

Comment: Be careful preparing code for pasting. Your editing software apparently converted plain quotes like " to fancy quotes like “ and ”. That interferes with other people copying your code and pasting it into a file to compile and test. Also, you missed a comma after the format string in `printf`. It is preferable to copy and paste code directly from a source file you have compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split this code into something longer but probably more readable like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=0, b=1, c=2;
    int *ptr;

    if (a + 1 == 1) { // this will be true
        ptr = &b;
    }
    else {
        ptr = &a;
    }

    if (a != 0) { // this will be false
        *ptr = b;
    }
    else {
        *ptr = c;
    }

    printf(“%d, %d, %d \n” a , b, c );

    return 0;
}
```

Based on the initial values, `a + 1 == 1` will be true, so `ptr = &b;`.

Since `a=0;` then `a != 0` will be false and thus `*ptr = c;`

==> same as `b = c;`

So the expected output is

> 0, 2, 2

Comment: Yeah thanks, I wasn't getting the logic but now it is crystal clear.